# React passing props (react-to-print)

Tags: reactjs, react-to-print

Hi I have been using this package `react-to-print` to print document and it works really well. Passing value to child component works and I can print the dynamic data too. However, I am facing problem to pass dynamic data of array list. It always gets the last item of array. I wrote an example, please take a look at it

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";
import ReactToPrint from "react-to-print";

const ComponentToPrint = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { value } = props;
  return (
    <div className="print-source" ref={ref}>
      Number {value}
    </div>
  );
});

export default function App() {
  const componentRef = useRef();

  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  return (
    <>
      {numbers.map(function (item, index) {
        return (
          <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <li key={index}>{item}</li>
            <ReactToPrint
              trigger={() => <button type="primary">Print</button>}
              content={() => componentRef.current}
            />
            <ComponentToPrint ref={componentRef} value={item} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-christian-o25b2)

Whenever I click the print button, I expect to send the unique value of number to child component but every time I am getting the last value of array. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there's just one `componentRef` instance, which on the order of rendering will have the last rendered value.

Instead each returned component from `App` needs to have its own instance of `componentRef`.

This can be achieved if you

1. make the returned html from `App` a component too (say `ComponentToPrintWrapper`)
2. have this component its own `componentRef`.

```js
const ComponentToPrintWrapper = ({ item }) => { // 1.
  const componentRef = useRef(); // 2.

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <li>{item}</li>
      <ReactToPrint
        trigger={() => <button type="primary">Print</button>}
        content={() => componentRef.current}
      />
      <ComponentToPrint ref={componentRef} value={item} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

3. Use `ComponentToPrintWrapper` on your `App` instead

```js
...
export default function App() {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  return (
    <>
      {numbers.map(function (item, index) {
        return <ComponentToPrintWrapper key={index} item={item} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
...
}
```

This will ensure each return element has its own `componentRef` instead.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-water-pzylr?file=/src/App.js)